# Communication between two composite components

Tags: java, jsf

I have two independent JSF composite components.
I want the second one to use some properties of the first one.

For example: rich:scroller has a property "for" which is used to indicate rich:dataTable component that scroller work with.

Likewise i have a composite component (a modal dialog) which will be called by other composites (some composite command link components).
Simply, different command links will open different modal dialogs...
I want to add a "modalPanel" property to my command link composites.
Then they will be aware of which modal dialog to open..

ModalPanel composite would be something like below:

```
<fl:modalPanel id="actModal"
                insideXhtml="../../aaactmodal.xhtml"
                dataBean="#{aaAct}" />
```

And the CommandLink composite would be like below:

```
<fl:modalLink dataBean="#{aaAct}"
                modalPanel="actModal" />
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Your question is sound, but a bit too broad. If you elaborate the concrete functional requirement (for which you thought that *this* is the solution) in detail, then we may be able to propose a detailed solution.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I updated the question. What do you think now ? BR.

Comment: Okay, that's better. But at which step exactly are you stucking? Opening the modal dialog by JavaScript? How exactly is the modal panel in the composite represented? If it were for example PrimeFaces `<p:dialog>`, you could just have used `<p:dialog widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.id}">` and then in the link just add `onclick="#{cc.attrs.modalPanel}.show()"` (or on `oncomplete`). Is that what you're concretely asking for?

Comment: Thank you very much BalusC. I realized my mistake after your message. I had added some attributes to modal panel composite component like "formId", "panelId" etc. Because I thought they would not be unique pagewise if I do not set them manually. Then I realized that all composites are also a NamingContainer. Now I removed those additional fields "formId", "panelId" etc. and gave them specific static names inside the modal form. They are not needed to be parametric to be able use them in command link composites.. Best Regards.